# Sharepoint 2010 Migration - SSRS Integrated Mode - Report Category View not displaying names?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, sharepoint-designer

We just migrated to SP 2010 and I am trying to migrate a report library. I had no problems updating the project and re-deploying reports. They work just fine. The problem is that in my Default View or any Report Category view the report names are not visible. I double checked that the names are visible in properties. If I add a Title or Description they show up just fine. For some reason the name will just not display.

The only way I can get the names is the All Reports and Dashboards view.

Here is a screenshot of my Default View:
[image]

I suppose I can just use the Title field as a work around. But that solution does not allow the user to click the name to view the report and that is what they are used to.

I can view the reports by clicking the type image. Any ideas of why the name will not display are greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the solution. In SP 2007 the default view was using the column Report Name. Changing it do Document Name instead resolved the issue.